# Exponencial function where I give $x$ to $x$ and it'll return me an exponential function between $0$ and $1$.

Tags: exponential-function

Sorry my enlgish isn't very good. I'm looking for a function that if, for example, I want
$x=$ from 300 to 24

and it'll give me y between $0$ and $1$ exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

A linear function that maps the domain $[24,300]$ to the range $[0,1]$: $$f(x)=\frac{x-24}{300-24}$$

An exponential function that maps the domain $[24,300]$ to the range $[0,1]$: $$g(x)=N^{f(x)-1}$$

You can use any $N>1$.

---

A linear function that maps the domain $[300,24]$ to the range $[0,1]$: $$f(x)=1-\frac{x-24}{300-24}$$

An exponential function that maps the domain $[300,24]$ to the range $[0,1]$: $$g(x)=N^{f(x)-1}$$

You can use any $N>1$.